# Pan responder interrupts scrollview scrolling

Tags: react-native, panresponder

I am using a panresponder for each item of the flat-list. I want the pan responder to respond oly when the user swipes from left to right. But pan responder is getting active also when i am scrolling . I want that there will be no interuption while scrolling

Comment: check properties of ScrollView https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

Comment: Yes i have checked but i don't think there is something which can help me out with this in scrollView properties. If you know anything about that can help me out please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have found a solution for this problem. It basically happens because the scrollView/Flatlist itself uses one responder to sense the gesture and i am also using one pan Responder . So two pan responders cannot work at same time. So the fix for this is when my pan responder becomes active at that time i disables my flatList scrolling and when the pan responder is released or the panresponderEnd method is called i enables the flatlist scrolling . So this way i solved my problem.

I also tell about a problem that faced when i was using panresponder that sometimes panresponder release method is not called , so the card get stucks in the middle. So i used panresponderEnd method which will be called every time when you release it .